# Area plot with missing values in base R

Tags: r, plot, time-series, missing-data

I want to draw an area plot for which the base of the polygon is zero and the data lines are connected to the base by vertical segments at every data break (that is the beginning, the end and possible NAs/NaN).

I drew this:

[image: time serie]

I had to force vertical down ward segments where the serie is interrupted with NAs, and I did this transforming NAs in 0s. But that doesn't produce vertical segments but polygon lines that reach the following 0s. I solved the problem for the beginning and the end of the series, adding a (y = 0, x = 0) point on both sides on the serie.

But this doesn't fix the problem if the NAs are inside the serie.

Any idea?

here's an example code (different image):

```
pollen <- c(45, 257.4, 24.67, 54.6, 89.4, 297, 471.25, 1256.5, 312.25, 969.2, 787.5, 425, NaN, 76.6, 42.67, 38.5, 20.2, 5.67, 15.8, 13.2, 11, 6.25, 6.67, 2.3, 0.5, 30.8, 3.75, 3, 2, 2.2, 3.25, 4.5, 9.6, 15.8, 200.2, NaN)

weeks.vec <- c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40)

plot.ts(y = pollen, x = weeks.vec, col = 'red', ylab = 'Pollen',  xlab = 'Weeks', lwd = 3, xy.labels = F, xy.lines = T)
pollen[is.na(pollen)] <- 0

poly.y <- c(0,pollen,0)
poly.x <- c(weeks.vec[1], weeks.vec, weeks.vec[length(weeks.vec)])

polygon(y = poly.y, x = poly.x, density = NA,border = NA, col = rgb(1,0,0, .3))
```

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Added code, please remove down vote if satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use ggplot2:

```
pollen <- c(45, 257.4, 24.67, 54.6, 89.4, 297, 471.25, 1256.5, 312.25, 969.2, 787.5, 425, NaN, 76.6, 42.67, 38.5, 20.2, 5.67, 15.8, 13.2, 11, 6.25, 6.67, 2.3, 0.5, 30.8, 3.75, 3, 2, 2.2, 3.25, 4.5, 9.6, 15.8, 200.2, NaN)

weeks.vec <- c(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40)


DF <- data.frame(pollen, weeks.vec)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = weeks.vec, y = pollen)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = pollen), 
              colour = NA, fill = "red", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(colour = "red") + 
  geom_point(colour = "red", size = 3) +
  xlab("Week") + ylab("Pollen") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image: resulting plot]

But if you must use base plots:

```
plot.ts(y = pollen, x = weeks.vec, col = 'red', 
        ylab = 'Pollen',  xlab = 'Weeks', lwd = 3, 
        xy.labels = F, xy.lines = T)

g <- cumsum(!is.finite(pollen))
for (i in unique(g)) {
  y <- pollen[g == i]
  x <- weeks.vec[g == i]
  x <- x[is.finite(y)]
  y <- y[is.finite(y)]
  x <- c(x, rev(x))
  y <- c(y, y * 0)
  polygon(y = y, x = x, density = NA,border = NA, col = rgb(1,0,0, .3))
}
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: the basic r code works! the ggplot gives me this error: "In if (class(trial) != "try-error") return(trial) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used" and drew points in the NA places, connected by full segments.

Comment: The ggplot2 code works with the example data you provided. If it doesn't work with your real data, the example data is not representative of it.

Comment: no no! I copy pasted the code! Anyway the basic r code works totally, I was waiting for alternative answers to learn more, otherways your one is definetely correct!